# get process id and parent process in solaris kernel module

Tags: c, solaris, kernel-module

In solaris 11.0 kernel module driver, I need to get the parent process id and start time, and continue doing it - climb up the process tree this way.

in Linux kernel I have struct_task contains process id, start time.
What is equivelant to struct_task, and how I can get it within process context ?

Thanks

I saw something like what i need but for **userspace**. but "open" cannot be used in kernel space..

```
char psfile[64];
pid_t pid;
int fd;
psinfo_t psinfo;
pid = getpid();
sprintf(psfile, "/proc/%d/psinfo", pid);
if ((fd = open(psfile, O_RDONLY)) >= 0) {
if (read(fd, &psinfo, sizeof(psinfo_t)) != -1) {
printf("Pid: %ld\n", psinfo.pr_pid);
printf("Up Start: (%ld, %ld)\n", psinfo.pr_start.tv_sec,  
psinfo.pr_start.tv_nsec);
printf("Command: %s\n", psinfo.pr_fname);
return 0;
}
} else {
perror("Open psfino");
}
```

the whole concept of /proc/procid/psinfo is to allow userspace processes to read kernel data. Since im at kernel space, i need to get the data from /proc/procid/psinfo if im on kernel space, this is disk IO i avoid...

Comment: Have you looked at getppid()?

Comment: I cant use the fd = open(psfile, O_RDONLY)) >= 0) .. I get message that open is invalid, Is this the proper way ? to open /proc/"getppid()"/psinfo and get the data ? from kernel space also ?

Comment: Does your program have the permissions to do this? Last I knew, /proc/ was protected.

Comment: I am kernel module, Dont I have permission to do whatever i want ? How do i open  /proc/"getppid()"/psinfo ?

Comment: To be the kernel, you must have access to all the kernel code.  Suggest researching for where the '/prop/ is updated, then use that same function calls, only setting the 'mode' to read rather than write.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{',  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line

Comment: the calls to `printf()` do not work as expected inside the kernel.  Suggest using `printk()`

Comment: @user3629249 the code i put is for userspace.. thats why the printf, i updated the question.. i need it for kernel space, why from kernel would i go to filesystem to get data that already should exist within kernel.

Comment: you might want to look into the `aio` library of functions

Comment: why, how would aio help me, im in kernel module, i want to get info on a process, without going to filesystem /proc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [look in `/usr/include/sys/thread.h`](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/thread.h#532), you'll see the macro `currproc` defined:

```
#define curproc     (ttoproc(curthread))    /* current process pointer */
```

That returns a `struct proc *` that if non-null refers to the current process.

The definition of `struct proc` can be [found in `/usr/include/sys/proc.h`](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/proc.h#139):

```
/*
 * One structure allocated per active process.  It contains all
 * data needed about the process while the process may be swapped
 * out.  Other per-process data (user.h) is also inside the proc structure.
 * Lightweight-process data (lwp.h) and the kernel stack may be swapped out.
 */
typedef struct  proc {
    /*
     * Fields requiring no explicit locking
     */
    struct  vnode *p_exec;      /* pointer to a.out vnode */
    struct  as *p_as;       /* process address space pointer */
    struct  plock *p_lockp;     /* ptr to proc struct's mutex lock */
    kmutex_t p_crlock;      /* lock for p_cred */
    struct  cred    *p_cred;    /* process credentials */
    /*
     * Fields protected by pidlock
     */
    int p_swapcnt;      /* number of swapped out lwps */
    char    p_stat;         /* status of process */
    char    p_wcode;        /* current wait code */
    ushort_t p_pidflag;     /* flags protected only by pidlock */
    int     p_wdata;        /* current wait return value */
    pid_t   p_ppid;         /* process id of parent */
    struct  proc    *p_link;    /* forward link */
    struct  proc    *p_parent;  /* ptr to parent process */
    struct  proc    *p_child;   /* ptr to first child process */
    struct  proc    *p_sibling; /* ptr to next sibling proc on chain */
    struct  proc    *p_psibling;    /* ptr to prev sibling proc on chain */
    struct  proc    *p_sibling_ns;  /* prt to siblings with new state */
    struct  proc    *p_child_ns;    /* prt to children with new state */
    struct  proc    *p_next;    /* active chain link next */
    struct  proc    *p_prev;    /* active chain link prev */
    struct  proc    *p_nextofkin;   /* gets accounting info at exit */
    struct  proc    *p_orphan;
    struct  proc    *p_nextorph;
    struct  proc    *p_pglink;  /* process group hash chain link next */
    struct  proc    *p_ppglink; /* process group hash chain link prev */
    struct  sess    *p_sessp;   /* session information */
    struct  pid     *p_pidp;    /* process ID info */
    struct  pid     *p_pgidp;   /* process group ID info */
    /*
     * Fields protected by p_lock
     */
    kcondvar_t p_cv;        /* proc struct's condition variable */
    kcondvar_t p_flag_cv;
    kcondvar_t p_lwpexit;       /* waiting for some lwp to exit */
    kcondvar_t p_holdlwps;      /* process is waiting for its lwps */
                    /* to to be held.  */
    uint_t  p_proc_flag;        /* /proc-related flags */
    uint_t  p_flag;         /* protected while set. */
                    /* flags defined below */
    clock_t p_utime;        /* user time, this process */
    clock_t p_stime;        /* system time, this process */
    clock_t p_cutime;       /* sum of children's user time */
    clock_t p_cstime;       /* sum of children's system time */
    avl_tree_t *p_segacct;      /* System V shared segment list */
    avl_tree_t *p_semacct;      /* System V semaphore undo list */
    caddr_t p_bssbase;      /* base addr of last bss below heap */
    caddr_t p_brkbase;      /* base addr of heap */
    size_t  p_brksize;      /* heap size in bytes */
    uint_t  p_brkpageszc;       /* preferred heap max page size code */
    /*
     * Per process signal stuff.
     */
    k_sigset_t p_sig;       /* signals pending to this process */
    k_sigset_t p_extsig;        /* signals sent from another contract */
    k_sigset_t p_ignore;        /* ignore when generated */
    k_sigset_t p_siginfo;       /* gets signal info with signal */
    void *p_sigfd;          /* signalfd support state */
    struct sigqueue *p_sigqueue;    /* queued siginfo structures */
    struct sigqhdr *p_sigqhdr;  /* hdr to sigqueue structure pool */
    struct sigqhdr *p_signhdr;  /* hdr to signotify structure pool */
    uchar_t p_stopsig;      /* jobcontrol stop signal */

    /*
     * Special per-process flag when set will fix misaligned memory
     * references.
     */
    char    p_fixalignment;

    /*
     * Per process lwp and kernel thread stuff
     */
    id_t    p_lwpid;        /* most recently allocated lwpid */
    int     p_lwpcnt;       /* number of lwps in this process */
    int p_lwprcnt;      /* number of not stopped lwps */
    int p_lwpdaemon;        /* number of TP_DAEMON lwps */
    int p_lwpwait;      /* number of lwps in lwp_wait() */
    int p_lwpdwait;     /* number of daemons in lwp_wait() */
    int p_zombcnt;      /* number of zombie lwps */
    kthread_t *p_tlist;     /* circular list of threads */
    lwpdir_t *p_lwpdir;     /* thread (lwp) directory */
    lwpdir_t *p_lwpfree;        /* p_lwpdir free list */
    tidhash_t *p_tidhash;       /* tid (lwpid) lookup hash table */
    uint_t  p_lwpdir_sz;        /* number of p_lwpdir[] entries */
    uint_t  p_tidhash_sz;       /* number of p_tidhash[] entries */
    ret_tidhash_t *p_ret_tidhash;   /* retired tidhash hash tables */
    uint64_t p_lgrpset;     /* unprotected hint of set of lgrps */
                    /* on which process has threads */
    volatile lgrp_id_t  p_t1_lgrpid; /* main's thread lgroup id */
    volatile lgrp_id_t  p_tr_lgrpid; /* text replica's lgroup id */
#if defined(_LP64)
    uintptr_t  p_lgrpres2;      /* reserved for lgrp migration */
#endif
    /*
     * /proc (process filesystem) debugger interface stuff.
     */
    k_sigset_t p_sigmask;       /* mask of traced signals (/proc) */
    k_fltset_t p_fltmask;       /* mask of traced faults (/proc) */
    struct vnode *p_trace;      /* pointer to primary /proc vnode */
    struct vnode *p_plist;      /* list of /proc vnodes for process */
    kthread_t *p_agenttp;       /* thread ptr for /proc agent lwp */
    avl_tree_t p_warea;     /* list of watched areas */
    avl_tree_t p_wpage;     /* remembered watched pages (vfork) */
    watched_page_t *p_wprot;    /* pages that need to have prot set */
    int p_mapcnt;       /* number of active pr_mappage()s */
    kmutex_t p_maplock;     /* lock for pr_mappage() */
    struct  proc  *p_rlink;     /* linked list for server */
    kcondvar_t p_srwchan_cv;
    size_t  p_stksize;      /* process stack size in bytes */
    uint_t  p_stkpageszc;       /* preferred stack max page size code */

    /*
     * Microstate accounting, resource usage, and real-time profiling
     */
    hrtime_t p_mstart;      /* hi-res process start time */
    hrtime_t p_mterm;       /* hi-res process termination time */
    hrtime_t p_mlreal;      /* elapsed time sum over defunct lwps */
    hrtime_t p_acct[NMSTATES];  /* microstate sum over defunct lwps */
    hrtime_t p_cacct[NMSTATES]; /* microstate sum over child procs */
    struct lrusage p_ru;        /* lrusage sum over defunct lwps */
    struct lrusage p_cru;       /* lrusage sum over child procs */
    struct itimerval p_rprof_timer; /* ITIMER_REALPROF interval timer */
    uintptr_t p_rprof_cyclic;   /* ITIMER_REALPROF cyclic */
    uint_t  p_defunct;      /* number of defunct lwps */
    /*
     * profiling. A lock is used in the event of multiple lwp's
     * using the same profiling base/size.
     */
    kmutex_t p_pflock;      /* protects user profile arguments */
    struct prof p_prof;     /* profile arguments */

    /*
     * Doors.
     */
    door_pool_t     p_server_threads; /* common thread pool */
    struct door_node    *p_door_list;   /* active doors */
    struct door_node    *p_unref_list;
    kcondvar_t      p_unref_cv;
    char            p_unref_thread; /* unref thread created */

    /*
     * Kernel probes
     */
    uchar_t         p_tnf_flags;

    /*
     * Solaris Audit
     */
    struct p_audit_data *p_audit_data; /* per process audit structure */

    pctxop_t    *p_pctx;

#if defined(__x86)
    /*
     * LDT support.
     */
    kmutex_t    p_ldtlock;  /* protects the following fields */
    user_desc_t *p_ldt;     /* Pointer to private LDT */
    system_desc_t   p_ldt_desc; /* segment descriptor for private LDT */
    ushort_t    p_ldtlimit; /* highest selector used */
#endif
    size_t p_swrss;         /* resident set size before last swap */
    struct aio  *p_aio;     /* pointer to async I/O struct */
    struct itimer   **p_itimer; /* interval timers */
    timeout_id_t    p_alarmid;  /* alarm's timeout id */
    caddr_t     p_usrstack; /* top of the process stack */
    uint_t      p_stkprot;  /* stack memory protection */
    uint_t      p_datprot;  /* data memory protection */
    model_t     p_model;    /* data model determined at exec time */
    struct lwpchan_data *p_lcp; /* lwpchan cache */
    kmutex_t    p_lcp_lock; /* protects assignments to p_lcp */
    utrap_handler_t *p_utraps;  /* pointer to user trap handlers */
    struct corectl_path *p_corefile;    /* pattern for core file */
    struct task *p_task;    /* our containing task */
    struct proc *p_taskprev;    /* ptr to previous process in task */
    struct proc *p_tasknext;    /* ptr to next process in task */
    kmutex_t    p_sc_lock;  /* protects p_pagep */
    struct sc_page_ctl *p_pagep;    /* list of process's shared pages */
    struct rctl_set *p_rctls;   /* resource controls for this process */
    rlim64_t    p_stk_ctl;  /* currently enforced stack size */
    rlim64_t    p_fsz_ctl;  /* currently enforced file size */
    rlim64_t    p_vmem_ctl; /* currently enforced addr-space size */
    rlim64_t    p_fno_ctl;  /* currently enforced file-desc limit */
    pid_t       p_ancpid;   /* ancestor pid, used by exacct */
    struct itimerval p_realitimer;  /* real interval timer */
    timeout_id_t    p_itimerid; /* real interval timer's timeout id */
    struct corectl_content *p_content;  /* content of core file */

    avl_tree_t  p_ct_held;  /* held contracts */
    struct ct_equeue **p_ct_equeue; /* process-type event queues */

    struct cont_process *p_ct_process; /* process contract */
    list_node_t p_ct_member;    /* process contract membership */
    sigqueue_t  *p_killsqp; /* sigqueue pointer for SIGKILL */

    int     p_dtrace_probes; /* are there probes for this proc? */
    uint64_t    p_dtrace_count; /* number of DTrace tracepoints */
                    /* (protected by P_PR_LOCK) */
    void        *p_dtrace_helpers; /* DTrace helpers, if any */
    struct pool *p_pool;    /* pointer to containing pool */
    kcondvar_t  p_poolcv;   /* synchronization with pools */
    uint_t      p_poolcnt;  /* # threads inside pool barrier */
    uint_t      p_poolflag; /* pool-related flags (see below) */
    uintptr_t   p_portcnt;  /* event ports counter */
    struct zone *p_zone;    /* zone in which process lives */
    struct vnode    *p_execdir; /* directory that p_exec came from */
    struct brand    *p_brand;   /* process's brand  */
    void        *p_brand_data;  /* per-process brand state */
    psecflags_t p_secflags; /* per-process security flags */

    /* additional lock to protect p_sessp (but not its contents) */
    kmutex_t p_splock;
    rctl_qty_t  p_locked_mem;   /* locked memory charged to proc */
                    /* protected by p_lock */
    rctl_qty_t  p_crypto_mem;   /* /dev/crypto memory charged to proc */
                    /* protected by p_lock */
    clock_t p_ttime;        /* buffered task time */

    /*
     * The user structure
     */
    struct user p_user;     /* (see sys/user.h) */
} proc_t;
```

So your current process id is `curproc->p_pidp->pid_id` and the parent process id is `curproc->p_ppid`.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i needed, works great. Should i check curproc for null befor eusing ? is it possible to have curproc null value within context of kernel module ??

Comment: An example of a right way of finding this information would be through getppid in libc and finally getpid in the kernel. Going directly into headers does not show you how the kernel gets the information (perhaps there is more to it than just reading a field). The more important problem though is that you provided this without asking OP what they need this for. The request is odd in both that such traversal is rarely legitimate and if someone really needed to do it, they would be able to find the information on their own.

Comment: @ilansch *Should i check curproc for null befor eusing ? is it possible to have curproc null value within context of kernel module ??*  I would check it. The posted code is for *OpenSolaris*, so there could be some differences. Given you're writing a kernel module where a null pointer dereference crashes the host, the small performance hit is probably worthwhile.

Comment: What is the field of process start time "p_mstart"  ? Its not equal to the field received from psinfo->psinfo.pr_start